# Hosting site or target not detected in firebase.json

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

I've just created a new Firebase project, and I'm trying to get my Angular app hosted properly but I'm getting `Hosting site or target partwizard not detected in firebase.json` when I try to run `ng deploy`.

I'm following the steps on the official Angular docs here: https://angular.io/start/start-deployment#hosting-an-angular-app-on-firebase

My dist folder that is built on `ng build --prod` is `dist/projectName`, I've tried using

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    ]
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/projectName",
    ]
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    ]
  }
}
```

But none work.

Answer (score 13):

May I suggest:

```
{
  "hosting": [{
    "target": "partwizard",
    "public": path to the folder containing your index.html
  }]
}
```

Comment: This one works! Especially for those using Firebase with Angular, the property `target` is not conveniently set via the `firebase init hosting`,

Answer (score 3):

So full process is

```
sudo ng build --prod
```

Not doing the above step will leave your app page at the welcome title.

```
sudo firebase init

single app yes

Overwrite index No
```

Now for some odd reason, after `firebase init` happens, it will delete site in your `firebase.json`, just add it again.

```
 "site": "YOUR-SITE",
```

then

```
sudo firebase deploy --only hosting:YOUR-SITE
```

`firebase init` deleting `site` in `firebase.json` seems like a new thing happening, took me awhile to figure it out.

Comment: that was what solved my issues, adding the site value

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by logging out of firebase in the CLI and logging back in, reinitializing the firebase project, and deploying worked.